# Screenshot reader for Mac

Tags: mac, screen-capture

Is there a screenshot reader similar to ABBYY Screenshot Reader (you are just selecting area on the screen and getting text into the buffer, something like that)?

Comment: Could you clarify the question ? Yo are looking for utility that will combine taking screenshots and then doing some sort of OCR so you can get editable text ?

Comment: Related: [Simple, free OCR software (for OS X)?](http://superuser.com/q/9916)

Comment: @Kassym Dorsel exactly!

Comment: Get yourself some OCR software and set up folder actions to run screenshots thru the OCR after you take them.

Answer (score 1):

how about using FreeOCR? It works for PDF files, TIFF images and can turn image to word file.

Comment: Might help if it wasn't Windows only - or do you have a Mac link?

Comment: oh, sorry, you may search Prizmo, it works on Mac, but it's not for free.